# Call an event containing parameter from another event in c#

Tags: c#

I want to call the event from within another event.

I want to call this event
`private void gv_client_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){}`

From this event as

```
private void update_staff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

 //some codes
 gv_client_CellContentClick(); // i want to call this event here

}
```

Comment: Do you want _raise_ the event? Or do you want to call this specific event handler?

Comment: I want to call the event which already exists.

Comment: There is a difference, you _raise_ or _handle_ an event but you _call_ a method. It gets confusing when you consider that a _handler_ is just a method that can be _called_. It seems like you want to simply call the `gv_client_CellContentClick`... Is that right? If so, it's a matter of ensuring that you have the correct object context on which to call this method, then call it like any other method (note: you may need to work out appropriate values for the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`).

Comment: Yes i am trying to achieve as you have thought but How call like any other method.I provide parameter as answer given below , it produce error,i dont provide para its wrong for sure.So?

Answer (score 0):

If the event is in same class you can call it like

```
private void update_staff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
//some codes
 gv_client_CellContentClick(sender,e); // i want to call this event here

}
```

Comment: Ahh sory its an object of DataGridViewCellEventArgs. In this case the only option you got is to set row & column index in global variable or use property, and then do it the Reddog way

Answer (score 0):

As per our comment thread, it seems you want to *call* the method (as opposed to raising the event).

In your original handler, you can simply call the method:

```
private void update_staff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rowIndex = ???;
    var columnIndex = ???;
    var args = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(columnIndex, rowIndex);
    gv_client_CellContentClick(sender, args); // Note: You might need to change sender too if you know this function uses it...
}
```

The bit you'll need to figure out is the row/column indexes. Presumably this can be retrieved based on the location of the "update_staff" button/control being clicked - tip: cast "sender" to whatever control type you know it is to work out which button/control was clicked.